# Memory difference between pyspark and spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have been trying to get a PySpark job to work which creates a RDD with a bunch of binary files, and then I use a `flatMap` operation to process the binary data into a bunch of rows.  This has lead to a bunch of out of memory errors, and after playing around with memory settings for a while I have decided to get the simplest thing possible working, which is just counting the number of files in the RDD.

This also fails with OOM error.  So I opened up both the spark-shell and PySpark and ran the commands in the REPL/shell with default settings, the only additional parameter was `--master yarn.`  The `spark-shell`version works, while the PySpark version shows the same OOM error.

Is there that much overhead to running PySpark?  Or is this a problem with `binaryFiles` being new?  I am using Spark version 2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91.

Comment: An additional data point is that if I load the data as <code>textFile</code> instead of <code>binaryFiles</code> in PySpark I do not seem to get the out of memory errors when I run <code>count()</code>, however it is extremely slow.

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for this kind of additional info - edit & update your post instead!

Answer (score 2):

The difference:

- Scala will load records as `PortableDataStream` - this means process is lazy, and unless you call `toArray` on the values, won't load data at all.
- Python will call Java backend, but load the data as byte array. This part will be eager-ish, therefore might fail on both sides.

Additionally PySpark will use at least twice as much memory - for Java and Python copy.

Finally `binaryFiles` (same as `wholeTextFiles`) are very inefficient and don't perform well, if individual input files are large. In case like this it is better to implement format specific Hadoop input format.

Answer (score 1):

Since  you are reading multiple binary files with binaryFiles() and starting Spark 2.1, the minPartitions argument of binaryFiles() is ignored

1.try to repartition the input files based on the following:
`enter code here`rdd = sc.binaryFiles(Path to the binary file , minPartitions = ).repartition()

2.You may try reducing the partition size to 64 MB or less depending on your size of the data using below config's

```
spark.files.maxPartitionBytes, default 128 MB
spark.files.openCostInBytes, default 4 MB
spark.default.parallelism
```